# Intersection operation on a list of comma separated string

Tags: c#

I have a list of comma separated string like below:

```
    List<string> IdList=new List<string>();
```

and each element of list has comma separated string like

```
     1,2,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,15,16
     2,3,5,7,8,9,0,10,16,17
     4,5,89,12,13,1,2,3,6,7,10,16
```

I want to apply AND operation on this list of string so I get output like below:

```
      2,5,7,10,16
```

Is there any efficient way  to implement Intersection  operation?

Comment: How many strings do you *really* have, and how important is performance, exactly? Because fundamentally this is a `List<List<int>>` by the looks of it - and that would be easier to manage...

Comment: Any number of string.the Length of List is not fix.

Comment: So what you want to do is find the values which exist in all of the lists? Are the individual values limited to integers, or are other types of values possible too?

Comment: @Michael Kjörling Yes values exist in all string in a list.value is always integers

Comment: This is bit wise AND that you are talking about?

Comment: Maybe, the term "set intersection" might be better then "AND" in this context.

Comment: @MaheshChitroda: You haven't answered either of my questions...

Comment: @JonSkeet Any number of string.the Length of List is not fix

Comment: @MaheshChitroda: Well I don't think it'll actually be *any* number, will it? Will you ever be asked to handle a billion strings? What about a million? Just because it's not absolutely fixed doesn't mean you don't have more context to tell us...

Comment: @Jon Skeet List has maximum 1000 strings.

Comment: @MaheshChitroda And how many lists are we talking about; ten, a thousand, a million, a billion?

Comment: @Michael Kjörling I have only one List but list has many string say maximum 1000.

Comment: @MaheshChitroda: And how many integers per string, as a maximum?

Comment: @Jon Skeet I don't know it's not fix but more than 2000.

Comment: @MaheshChitroda So at most, you are dealing with on the order of two million individual values? What is the numerical range of those values?

Comment: @Michael Kjörling  numerical ranges of those values is from 1 to 200000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're actually looking for an *intersection*.

If you don't need the values in numeric order, you could just treat each string as just comma-separated values. Start with the first list, and just intersect each other one appropriately:

```
HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(list[0].Split(','));
foreach (var item in list.Skip(1))
{
    set.IntersectWith(item.Split(','));
}
string result = string.Join(",", set);
```

Complete sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Test
{
    static void Main()
    {
        var list = new List<string>
        {
            "1,2,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,15,16", 
            "2,3,5,7,8,9,0,10,16,17",
            "4,5,89,12,13,1,2,3,6,7,10,16"
        };

        HashSet<string> set = new HashSet<string>(list[0].Split(','));
        foreach (var item in list.Skip(1))
        {
            set.IntersectWith(item.Split(','));
        }
        string result = string.Join(",", set);
        Console.WriteLine(result);
    }
}
```

Result (order not guaranteed):

```
2,5,7,10,16
```

Comment: +1 for including complete sample code. (I'm not spiteful. :))

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about "less memory utilization", but my first shot at this would be something along these lines (untested, coded in browser, no Visual Studio handy yadda yadda):

```
Dictionary<int,int> occurences = new Dictionary<int,int>();
int numberOfLists = YourCollectionOfOuterLists.Count;

foreach (string list in YourCollectionOfOuterLists) {
    foreach (string value in list.Split(',')) {
        occurences[value] = ((occurences[value] as int) ?? 0) + 1;
    }
}

List<int> output = new List<int>();
foreach (int key in occurences.Keys) {
    if (occurences[key] == numberOfLists) {
        output.Add(key);
    }
}

return String.Join(output.Select(x => x.ToString()), ",");
```

It might very well be possible to write the code more tersely, but anything that accomplishes what you seem to be after will still have to perform roughly the same steps: decide which elements exist in all lists (which is slightly non-trivial as the number of lists is unknown), then make a new list out of those values.

If you have access to it, something like [`Parallel.ForEach()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.parallel.foreach.aspx) might help cut down on wallclock execution time at least of the second loop (and possibly the first, with proper locking/synchronization in place).

If you are after something other than this, please clarify your question to describe exactly what you want.

Comment: I know that we can achieve this in many way but I want a fast and efficient way which use less time because every string has thousands of element and a list has many string of such type.

Comment: `Dictionary<>` is pretty decent performance-wise, and a few tens of thousands of elements isn't that large a data set. Memory usage will likely be similar regardless of the implementation because the bulk of the memory usage will be to keep track of the candidate values. (Knowing the range of the input values you may be able to use a type with a smaller range than `int`; e.g., all your example values would fit perfectly in `byte`s.) Have you *determined* (e.g. using a profiler) that a naiive implementation is a major performance bottleneck or unacceptable memory hog?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about performance but you can use the `Aggregate` extension method to 'fold intersections'.

```
var data = new List<string>
{
    "1,2,4,5,6,7,8,10,12,15,16",
    "2,3,5,7,8,9,0,10,16,17",
    "4,5,89,12,13,1,2,3,6,7,10,16",
};

var fold = data.Aggregate(data[0].Split(',').AsEnumerable(), (d1, d2) => d1.Intersect(d2.Split(',')));
```